# Laravel redirect route with link in the view

Tags: laravel

I try to show a button in my view when a new licence is create on my store controller . Everything is fine till i want to display a link or a button to the view .

here my controller

```
public function store(LicencieProCreateRequest $request){
//
..
 return redirect('home')->with('status', "La Licence Pro pour : " . $licencie_pro->lb_nom . " à bien été crée ! " . route('licencie-joueur-pro.show', 'Voir la licence', [$licencie_pro->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) );

}
```

here my view Blade who display the notification with the URL but i would like a link or a button is it possible ?

```
@if (session('status')) 
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
  @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass status as variable:

```
return redirect('home')->with(['status'=>$status]);
```

and link to anywhere when clicking on the status:

```
@if ($status) 
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <a href="{{url('/')}}">{{$status}}</a>
    </div>
@endif
```